# Capture Avoiding Substitution of multiple variables at once

Tags: formal-languages, lambda-calculus

In articles you often find the terminus "capture avoiding substitution" that saves the author(s) from the tedious process to re-define a recursive function -including alpha-conversion and the invention of fresh names- in the discussion of dynamic semantics. The terminus is well understood by the readers and somewhat standard.

In order to provide an easy-to-read semantics, I recently defined a group of multiple recursive functions as a map from identifiers to (lambda-) terms. Application of one of these recursive functions then requires to substitute *all* free occurrences of its "siblings" in its body. It seems quite natural to introduce a generalization of substitution with partial functions instead of the usual univariate meta-function.

As an example consider the following group:

```
let rec fac n = if n <= 1 then 1 else n * (fac (n-1))
and foo n = fac n 

in let fac = 5 in foo fac
```

This gives a two-element partial function, where each right-hand side is mapped to the recursive group with its body:

$\sigma = \left\{(\mathtt{foo} \mapsto \lambda \mathtt{n}. \mathtt{let\ rec\ ... in\ fac\ n}), (\mathtt{fac} \mapsto \lambda \mathtt{n} . \mathtt{let\ rec ...})\right\}$

This substitution is then applied to the body of the let-rec. It should first rename the bound variable fac, since it occurs freely in the **codomain** of the partial function i.e.

```
... let fac0 = 5 in foo fac0
```

Then, the substitution should replace any mapped variable at once:

```
... let fac0 = 5 in ((let rec fac = ... and foo = ... in fac) fac0)
```

When I generalize this, I cannot assume that the right-hand terms are recursive definitions. Any term might occur on the codomain. In particular, they could contain free variables that are bound *by the substitution itself*. Therefore, the order of replacements matters: I need to ensure that a replacement is not immediately subject to substitution again. This can, of course be defined, but I'd rather just use a sentence similar to the one mentioned above.

Is there a standard definition of capture avoiding substitution of multiple variables?